# Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Tags: android, react-native

I have started to get today such an error in Android studio, when I'm trying to create release bundle.

Here is the error:

> Could not GET
>   'https://jitpack.io/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Any ideas how is possible to fix this?

Comment: getting this trying to build or run project

Comment: This error occurs during build

Comment: The author answered that the issue was solved by updating Android Studio. According to the most voted answer, this fix was a coincidence as the problem was a temporary error.

Answer (score 2):

add `www` to jitpack url to be like this

```
maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
```

not

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

Comment: after making this change, i get different errors. few of the libraries/packages i used cannot be found, like exoplayer and IMA....any idea?

Comment: Thanks this got me going while the issue was being resolved on their end

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by updating Android Studio to the latest version, somehow this error dissapeared after the update.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by updating all google-firebase libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is your link to download 'maven-metadata.xml' is out of dated.

- Upgrade your gradle to the latest version.
- Upgrade your Android Studio to the latest version.

In my case, I updated gradle from 5.6 to 6.5, fix "403 from server: Forbidden" issue

Answer (score 0):

In Directory `yourapp\android\gradle\wrapper\gradel-wrapper.properties` update `distributionUrl` to:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have forget to update my jitpack authToken token. when I replaced the old  authToken with new one its boom success